# PHP comparar valores de formulario con el contenido de un fichero

Tags: php

Tengo un form en el archivo login.PHP que recoge el usuario y la contraseña introducido por el usuario, y en un archivo usuarios.TXT tengo una serie de usuarios con sus contraseñas:

usu1:pass1 
usu2:pass2 
prueba:passprueba

como podria comparar lo introducido, con lo que hay en el usuarios.TXT?
se puede comparar linea por linea? porque en el caso que ponga como usuario : usu2 y contraseña: passprueba, seria erroneo puesto que si existen ambos valores, pero no en la misma linea, estoy super atascado.

de momento mi codigo es este:

```
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
        <p>Usuario:</p> <br>
        <input type="text" name="usuarioIntroducido"> <br>
        <p>Contraseña:</p> <br>
        <input type="password" name="contraseñaIntroducida" id=""> <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Click para entrar">
    </form>

    <?php    
    $usuarioIntroducido = $_POST["usuarioIntroducido"];
    $contraseñaIntroducida = $_POST["contraseñaIntroducida"];

    $fichero = "usuarios.txt";
    $contenidoFichero = file_get_contents($fichero);
    ?>

Muchas gracias! ^^
```

Comment: Leer cada línea y comparar tanto el nombre de usuario como la contraseña. Únicamente si ambos coinciden significa que es válido.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes leer el archivo línea por línea, hacer un `explode` de cada línea usando el separador `:` y comparar con los datos proporcionados.

El método adecuado para leer un archivo línea por línea es `fgets()`, pues `file_get_contents()` lo que hace es meter todo el archivo en una cadena, cosa que no interesa para este caso.

Esto debería funcionarte:

```
/*
   Verificamos que los POST no estén vacíos 
   guardando primero en una variable, usando fusión de null
*/
$user = $_POST["usuarioIntroducido"] ?? null;
$pass = $_POST["contraseñaIntroducida"] ?? null;

if ($user && $pass) {

    $fileName = "usuarios.txt";
    $file = new SplFileObject($fileName);
    $file->setFlags(SplFileObject::DROP_NEW_LINE);

    while (!$file->eof()) {
      /*
        Dividimos cada línea en dos partes
        para obtener usuario y contraseña
        */
      $parts=explode(":",$file->fgets());
    
      /*
        Verificamos para evitar problemas de undefined index
        */
      $tmpUser=$parts[0] ?? null;
      $tmpPass=$parts[1] ?? null;
    
      /*
        Comprobamos que las variables no son nulas
        y que además coinciden ....
        Si coinciden, salimos del bucle
        */
      if ( $tmpUser && $tmpPass && $tmpUser==$user && $tmpPass==$pass) {
        printf("%s es igual a %s y %s es igual a %s %s",$tmpUser,$user,$tmpPass,$pass,PHP_EOL);
        break;
      }else{
        printf("%s NO es igual a %s y %s NO es igual a %s %s",$tmpUser,$user,$tmpPass,$pass,PHP_EOL);
      }
    }
} else {
    echo "No se postearon los datos, revise el formulario";
}
```

Nótese que he preferido una convención de nombre en inglés, que permite variables más abreviadas. Deberías evitar igualmente usar `ñ` y acentos en tus variables y nombres de elementos HTML. Si no hilas fino en la codificación, tu código podría fallar gravemente.

He puesto varios comentarios en el código. Si tienes alguna duda, pregunta en comentarios.